# Directed graph reachability

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal

Given a directed graph G(V,E) and a node s, how do we determine what nodes are reachable from s? Do I need simple traversal algorithms or do I need to look at Tarjan's algorithm?

Comment: Just pick you favourite traversal algorithm (BFS, DFS...) from $s$. Tarjan's algorithm is for finding the strongly connected components of the graph. If you are interseted in the nodes which are **also** co-reachable from $s$, then go with Tarjan (or Kosaraju)

Answer (score 1):

Use depth-first search, or breadth-first search, or any other graph search algorithm.  You don't need Tarjan's algorithm.

Comment: Breadth-first search for solving the reachability problem? In the reachability problem it is not required to compute the shortest path, ... Not all algorithms would be the equally good for solving the reachability problem unless, of course, the graph is given explicitly and it is small enough to fit in memory ...